# hide meta tag, wrong syntax?

Tags: php, syntax, meta-tags

My programmer isn't available at the moment and I need to make a change to the system.

I have tried to copy what he has done before, but I keep getting errors.

So what I want to do is to have the metatags hidden when a url stats with /id.

He has done the same with the title tag like this:

```
<?php if (!StartsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/id/') echo "<title>$pagetitle</title>"; ?>
```

Result: title is hidden when an url goes like www.site.com/id=15

Below is the metatag as it is:

```
<?=isset($metatags) ? $metatags:"" ?>
```

I tried to copy things and make it hide the meta with the code below:

```
<?php if (!StartsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/id/') isset($metatags) ? $metatags:"" ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody be so kind to provide me with the correct line?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" a meta tag? Meta tags are not typically directly rendered by the browser.

Comment: those are just codes used by my marketplace; i just want to have the variable metatags not displayed when an url starts with id. (the id pages have all separated metas generated from their description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the existing "metatags" line with what your programmer has done previously to hide text based on the request URI, by saying:

```
<?= (isset($metatags) && !StartsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/id/')) ? $metatags : "" ?>
```

OR

```
<?php if (isset($metatags) && !StartsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/id/')) echo $metatags; ?>
```

They mean the same thing; you may use whichever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to `echo` it:

```
<?php if (!StartsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/id/') echo(isset($metatags) ? $metatags:""); ?>
```

If you look carefully, the original metatags code started with `<?=` which is just shorthand for `<?php echo`.

But as I was typing this, @Jonathan Newmuis posted a more elegant answer. Go with his.